# mobiscroll time step not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobiscroll

I have the following html and JS but am unable to get the step parameter to work for minutes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.gajotres.net/iscrollview/mobiscroll-2.4.custom.min.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.fajrunt.org/mobiscroll.custom-2.5.1.min.css"/>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://example.gajotres.net/iscrollview/mobiscroll-2.4.custom.min.js"></script>   

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>            
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <input name="demo" id="demo" class="i-txt" />
    </div>

</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the JS code that's giving me problems:

```
$(function(){       
$('#demo').mobiscroll().time({        

    display: 'inline',
    mode: 'scroller',
    steps: {                  
             minute: 15,                 
             zeroBased: true
           }

});  
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever get this solved?